# dygraphs native data doesn't work

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

I would like to ask for help on the following issue:

I was playing with the "Demo of the Range Selector" and was trying to generate data in the native format based on the Data format in the documentation

```
[
[ new Date("2009/07/12"), 100, ],
[ new Date("2010/07/19"), 250,],
[ new Date("2011/07/19"),350, ],
[ new Date("2012/07/19"), 450, ],
[ new Date("2013/07/19"), 250, ],
[ new Date("2014/07/19"), 350, ],
[ new Date("2015/07/19"), 550 ],
[ new Date("2016/07/19"), 650 ],
[ new Date("2017/07/19"), 150,]
```

],

but it doesn't show the data in the chart. I didn't change anything else.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
-I set the customBars to FALSE and introduced labels (labels: [ "x", "A", ],)